# How to visualize Kinematics or Classical Physics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, software, visualization

Is there a software or a website to visualize Kinematics? For example, I want to visualize different problems on pulley system. Is there a simulation app?

Comment: Search up how to simulate projectile motion in python

Comment: I can simulate projectile myself, but I need a sort of everything like pulley, spring, and all that which is hard to create in python for me.